# Initialization from incompatible pointer type when constructing a GTK combobox

Tags: c, gtk

```
GtkComboBoxText  *main_combo=gtk_combo_box_text_new();
```

The above code is yielding the following error:

> source.c:31:32: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>      GtkComboBoxText  *main_combo=gtk_combo_box_text_new();

I'm not sure I understand the meaning of the error or how it would be fixed.

Comment: The function returns GtkWidget\*

Comment: All widget constructors in GTK+ return `GtkWidget *`. I don't know why. There are two things you can do: either a) just have the one variable, of type `GtkWidget *`, and uses casts like `GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(widget)` when appropriate, or b) have one variable for each type in the class hierarchy for the widget's actual type, all pointing to the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Declare your combobox like this:

```
GtkWidget  *main_combo=gtk_combo_box_text_new();
```

And use it like this:

```
gtk_combo_box_text_insert(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(main_combo), 0, NULL, "foobar");
```

---

#### Long answer:

GTK widgets follow an object-oriented approach in which specific widget types inherit properties and methods from more general widget types.

For example, from the docs, `GtkComboBoxText` has the following hierarchy:

```
GObject
\-- GInitiallyUnowned
    \-- GtkWidget
        \-- GtkContainer
            \-- GtkBin
                \-- GtkComboBox
                    \-- GtkComboBoxText
```

In addition, a widget type can also implement interfaces. For example, from the docs,

> GtkComboBoxText implements AtkImplementorIface, GtkBuildable, GtkCellLayout and GtkCellEditable.

What this means is that, given a pointer `ptr` pointing to an object of type `GtkComboBoxText`, I could:

1. Use it on the methods for GtkComboBoxText, e.g.

   ```
   gtk_combo_box_text_insert(ptr, 0, NULL, "foobar");
   ```
2. Use it on the methods for any type it inherits from, e.g.

   ```
   gtk_widget_destroy(ptr);
   ```

   or

   ```
   GtkWidget *wid = gtk_bin_get_child(ptr);
   ```
3. Use it on the methods for any interface it implements, e.g.

   ```
   gtk_cell_editable_start_editing(ptr, event);
   ```

Because C is not an object-oriented language, when you compile your program the compiler does not know that `GtkComboBoxText` inherits from `GtkWidget`. What this means is that if you have an object declared with type `GtkComboBoxText`, the compiler would see an incompatible pointer when you use it in methods for `GtkWidget`, and vice versa.

Now the author of GTK has two sensible choices for an object constructor. For example, for `gtk_combo_box_text()`, they may choose for it to return `GtkComboBoxText *`, or they may choose a useful type at the top of the hierarchy (`GtkWidget *`) to return. They chose the latter.

So you actually have a few options to fix the warning message:

1. Cast your widget when you need to use it for the methods for the inherited types:

   ```
   GtkWidget *w = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
   gtk_combo_box_text_insert(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(w), 0, NULL, "foobar");
   gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(w), -1);
   gtk_buildable_set_name(GTK_BUILDABLE(w), "name");
   gtk_widget_destroy(w); // no cast needed here
   ```
2. Cast your widget when you initialize it:

   ```
   GtkComboBoxText *w = GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(gtk_combo_box_text_new());
   gtk_combo_box_text_insert(w, 0, NULL, "foobar"); // no cast needed here
   gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(w), -1);
   gtk_buildable_set_name(GTK_BUILDABLE(w), "name");
   gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(w));
   ```
3. Use `void *`:

   ```
   void *w = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
   gtk_combo_box_text_insert(w, 0, NULL, "foobar");
   gtk_combo_box_set_active(w, -1);
   gtk_buildable_set_name(w, "name");
   gtk_widget_destroy(w);
   ```

While the 3rd method may look neater, I personally would not recommend it since it may not detect some mistakes one might make. The 2nd method may have its advantage if you are calling the `gtk_combo_box_text_*()` functions very frequently and rarely use the other functions. However, I generally use the 1st method, as its usage is more clear and straightforward (i.e. don't cast when using `gtk_widget_*()` functions, cast otherwise). The 1st method is also the one used in the examples in the documentation and gtk3-demo.

*Side note:*

It is also possible to use the traditional C-style casts, like

```
gtk_combo_box_text_insert((GtkComboBoxText *)main_combo, 0, NULL, "foobar");
```

However, the macro `GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT()` provides some error checking so if you accidentally passed something that is not a GtkComboBoxText, the macro will cause an error message to be displayed while the C-style cast may not.

Comment: ace, I appreciate you taking the time to write this down in the simplified way you have
I have opted in for type 1 and the type casting has eliminated those messages.
also the information was EXTREMELY useful, I have learned alot reading that post.
thank you